# How read() / write() works with FIFO? - Issue in a client/server program

Tags: c, pipe, mkfifo

I have a client/server program.

Client does the following in a loop.

- writes string1 on a pipe.
- read a string from another pipe.
- writes string2 on the pipe.

Server does the following in a loop.

- reads the string.
- writes the same data to client on other pipe.

1. For some iterations this works fine, after approx 10 iterations only string2 is seen to be read on both client and server.
   Why this so? 
   Also, in in client program in while() loop if read() is called after 2nd write() everything works fine.
2. In client, from second iteration read() should return the whole data in pipe because pipe does not have message boundaries. But it just reads only the data written by 1 write() call in server.

Below is my code for reference.

server.c

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
 client_to_server;
char *myfifo = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";
int server_to_client;
char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

char buf[BUFSIZ];

 /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
 mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);
 mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666);

 /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
 client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
 server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);

 printf("Server ON bufsize=%d.\n", BUFSIZ);

 while (1)
 {
   read(client_to_server, buf, BUFSIZ);
  if (strcmp("exit",buf)==0)
  {
     printf("Server OFF.\n");
     break;
  }
  else if (strcmp("",buf)!=0)
  {
     printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
     printf("Sending back...\n");
     write(server_to_client,buf,BUFSIZ);
  }

  /* clean buf from any data */
  memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
 }

 close(client_to_server);
 close(server_to_client);
 unlink(myfifo);
 unlink(myfifo2);
 return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   int client_to_server;
   char *myfifo = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";
   int server_to_client;
   char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

   char str[BUFSIZ];

  /* write str to the FIFO */
  client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
  server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);

  char buf1[30] = "str1";
  char buf2[30] = "str2";

 while(1){

   //write first string
   write(client_to_server, buf1, sizeof(buf1));
   read(server_to_client,str,sizeof(str));
   perror("Read:"); // Very crude error check
   printf("...received from the server: %s\n",str);

   memset(str, '\0', sizeof(str));

  //write second string
  write(client_to_server, buf2, sizeof(buf2));
 }

 close(client_to_server);
 close(server_to_client);
 return 0;
}
```

Below is the output:
Server output:
Server ON bufsize=8192.
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str1
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2
Sending back...
Received: str2

Below is the output from client:
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str1
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2
...received from the server: str2

Comment: Did you mean to use `sizeof` here `write(client_to_server, buf1, sizeof(buf1));` since "potentially" you send "str1"and null, plus 25 more characters ?

Comment: How do you even know your `read()` and `write()` calls worked?

Comment: The output which I have given is getting displayed infinitely, that means read() and() write are working, if these calls were not working it would have stuck somewhere. Also, in client.c in the loop if I call read() after second write() everything works fine.

Comment: You don't check for errors, nor for the return value from `read(2)` which can be less than `BUFSIZ`.  Also, you need the number of bytes read in server code to write only those bytes.  The way you are doing is very prone to errors, as you don't check any errors coming from the system calls you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is the client and server receive "str2\0str1\0" but print just up to the first \0, i.e. "str2".

The long answer is on the client side that you send not just strings "str1" and "str2" but also the terminating NUL:

```
write(client_to_server, buf1, sizeof(buf1));
```

The sizeof here returns the length of the string plus terminating NUL.

Now the server side. You read up to BUFSIZ bytes. So if the client is fast enough to send few strings, i.e. "str2\0str1\0" you will read all strings in one go. To fix this you have to take into account what the read returns, i.e.:

```
ssize_t ret = read(client_to_server, buf, BUFSIZ);
printf("Received: size %zd\n", ret); // print the size
fwrite(buf, 1, ret, stdout); // print the buffer with NULs
write(server_to_client,buf,ret); // write back just the data you actually received
```

Comment: Thankyou Andriy. So, basically while reading from fifo, whole data available upto buffer size is read. There is no boundaries between data written by two writes(). If we have to pass structures through pipe we have to implement our own protocol to differentiate between two messages. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @user2137306 for variable size structures you definitely need some kind of a protocol, passing at least message size in message header. But if the size of a message is fixed, you just have to read/write message size buffers, not BUFSIZ. And just check you actually read/write this size.

Answer (score 0):

You don't check for errors, and don't use the return value from `read(2)` which says how many characters a read returns.  This is weird, as this is the source of unsynchronized server and client.  I have rewritten your code in a manner that doesn't fail (although I don't check the return value of `write(2)`, which should fail on breaking the pipes --- on killing server or client)  This is left for you to complete, as an exercise.

Focus on how the non null terminated strings are processed by `printf(3)` call, by specifying the length of the string with `"%.*s"` format (this is a trick to avoid to put the final `\0` in the buffer (which should be checked if you are reading up to `sizeof buf`, instead of `sizeof buf - 1`.

## server.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define F(fmt) __FILE__":%d:%s: " fmt, __LINE__, __func__

/* file scope to share with at_exit() call */
static const char myfifo[] = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";
static const char myfifo2[] = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

void rm_fifos(void)
{
    printf(F("deleting fifo \"%s\"\n"), myfifo);
    unlink(myfifo);
    printf(F("deleting fifo2 \"%s\"\n"), myfifo2);
    unlink(myfifo2);
}

int main()
{
    int client_to_server;
    int server_to_client;
    int res;

    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
    printf(F("creating fifo \"%s\"\n"), myfifo);
    res = mkfifo(myfifo, 0666 | O_EXCL); /* O_EXCL guarantees that no second instance is created while this is running */
    if (res < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: %s(errno=%d)\n"),
                    myfifo, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf(F("creating fifo \"%s\"\n"), myfifo);
    res = mkfifo(myfifo2, 0666 | O_EXCL);
    if (res < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: %s(errno=%d)\n"),
                    myfifo2, strerror(errno), errno);
            unlink(myfifo); /* we successfuly created it */
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    atexit(rm_fifos);

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    if (client_to_server < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: open: %s(errno=%d)\n"),
                    myfifo, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_WRONLY);
    if (server_to_client < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: open: %s(errno=%d)\n"),
                    myfifo2, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf(F("Server ON bufsize=%d.\n"), BUFSIZ);

    while (1) {
            ssize_t n = read(client_to_server, buf, BUFSIZ);
            if (n < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            F("%s: read: %s(errno = %d)\n"),
                            myfifo, strerror(errno), errno);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (n == 0) break;  /* EOF on input */

            printf("Received: [%.*s]\n", n, buf);
            printf("Sending back...\n");
            write(server_to_client, buf, n); /* very important to write just the n read chars, and not more */

            /* no need to clean buf from any data */
    }

    close(client_to_server);
    close(server_to_client);

    /* no need to unlink, as this was prepared in the atexit() library call */
    return 0;
}
```

## client.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define F(fmt) __FILE__ ":%d:%s: " fmt, __LINE__, __func__

int main()
{
    int client_to_server;
    char *myfifo = "/tmp/client_to_server_fifo";
    int server_to_client;
    char *myfifo2 = "/tmp/server_to_client_fifo";

    char str[BUFSIZ];

    /* write str to the FIFO */
    client_to_server = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    if (client_to_server < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: %s(errno = %d)\n"),
                    myfifo, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    server_to_client = open(myfifo2, O_RDONLY);
    if (server_to_client < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                    F("%s: %s(errno = %d)\n"),
                    myfifo2, strerror(errno), errno);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char buf1[30] = "str1";
    char buf1_length = strlen(buf1);
    char buf2[30] = "str2";
    char buf2_length = strlen(buf2);

    while(1) {

            ssize_t n;
            //write first string
            write(client_to_server, buf1, buf1_length);
            n = read(server_to_client, str, sizeof(str));
            if (n < 0) {
                    fprintf(stderr,
                            F("%s: %s(errno = %d)\n"),
                            myfifo2, strerror(errno), errno);
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (n == 0) break;

            printf("...received from the server: %.*s\n", n, str);

            /* NO NEED TO CLEAN THE BUFFER */

            //write second string
            write(client_to_server, buf2, buf2_length);
    }

    close(client_to_server);
    close(server_to_client);

    return 0;
}
```